# Sphinx: create RT index without reload searchd

Tags: sphinx

Is there any way to create RT without reloading the searchd?

For example, I have script generating sphinx.conf file, where the number of indexes
depends on how many instances of some class I have.

If I create another instance and reload searchd, then for some period of time other
instances can not use search.

Can I create RT indexes dynamically?

Comment: Am I right that ```kill -1 `cat path/to/pid\` ``` with `seamless_rotate = 1` in conf file will do the trick in some way? But can I reload not all indexes but the specific one?

Comment: How are you 'reloading' searchd? Sounds like you shutting it down, and starting it up again, which will entail a bit of downtime. Instead you should explicitly 'reload' it. If your init script doesnt have a reload option, then send SIGHUP to the process manaually. Eg with 'kill' command

Comment: Ah `kill -1` is SIGHUP was talking about :) Not sure seamless_rotate will make a direct difference as such, but keep it =1 is probably best.

Comment: @barryhunter thanks for help! But to make it all clear, SIGHUP will reload all indexes or just new ones? If all, are there any options to make it load only new ones? (to not waste memory)

Comment: Only new ones, or ones with new version available (files with .new. in filename, as prepared by indexer)